# Error in setting alert in radiobuttonlist?

Tags: javascript, radiobuttonlist

I have a two text box with radiobuttonlist.If the two test are blank it should alert "textbox are blank" and if its not blank it should alert "date is enabled".

This what i have tried with javascript

```
 function checked() {
        var radio = document.getElementById('<%=rbtn1.ClientId%>');
        var cal1 = document.getElementById('<%=textstqo.ClientId%>').value;
        var cal2 = document.getElementById('<%=textedqo.ClientId%>').value;
    if (radio.checked = true) {

         if(cal1 == '' && cal2 =='')
        {
        alert("dates cannot be blank");
        return false
        }else
        {
        alert("dates are enabled");
         return true
        }
        }

    }
```

Radio button list

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbtn1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Vertical" RepeatLayout="Table" Height="300px" Width="101px" onClick="checked()" >
 <asp:ListItem Text="one" Value="one" Enabled="true"></asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Text="two" Value="two" Enabled="true" ></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="three" Value="three" Enabled="true"></asp:ListItem>
```

Edited
Error: Function expected

The first alert is working .when i tried to check the alert in else part it shows the above error
I have only shown you the first radio button that is "quaterone" and the javascript is also for quaterone

Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrongly.Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you trying like, if any one of the radio button is checked then validate for text boxes, else leave it?

Comment: no.. only when the first radio button is clicked that is "quaterone"@

Comment: @shanish:no.. only when the first radio button is clicked that is "quaterone

Comment: // `when i tried to check the alert in else part it shows the above error I have only shown you the first radio button that is "quaterone" and the javascript is also for quaterone.`// 


Where exactly you are getting error. Is it from the source given in your question?

Comment: @shanish:The problem is i want alert only when  the first radio button (quaterone)in radibuttonlist is selected.but it shows the alert when i click the other radio button also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is you are using wrong id for the radio button. `'<%=rbtn1.ClientId%>_Quaterone'`

Try instead: `'<%=rbtn1.ClientId%>'`

***Edited:***

```
var radioCont = document.getElementById('<%=rbtn1.ClientId%>');
var radio = radioCont.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];//first radio
```

Also you are trying to assign value instead of comparison:

```
if (radio.checked = true) { //assignment
```

Try this:

```
if (radio.checked == true) { // though `===` is recommended over `==`
```

You may also try:

```
if(radio.checked) {
  // to do here
}
```

Change the attribute to `onchange` instead of `onclick`, here:

```
onClick="checked()" >
```

In order to uncheck the radio assign false to its state:

```
alert("dates cannot be blank");
radio.checked = false; //un-check the radio
return false;
```

Comment: it worked@Aravind ...but it shows the first alert but when i tried to check the else part its shows fuctoin expexted

Comment: when i tried both the method it did not show any alert@Arvind

Comment: arvind:The problem is i want alert only when the first radio button (quaterone)in radibuttonlist is selected.but it shows the alert when i click the other radio button also

Comment: arvind:thank you  it works:-)...another question is it possible to make selected radio to unselected after the alert "cannot be blank" appears.

Answer (score 0):

To validate only when the first radio button is checked, you can check it like

```
if($('#rbtn1 input:radio:checked').val() == 'quaterone'){
    // your condition here...
}
```